# su not working on mac os x?

Tags: mac-osx, sudo

I get this:

```
Macintosh:8.4 TAmoyal$ su
Password:
su: Sorry
Macintosh:8.4 TAmoyal$
```

I typed in the password I use for sudo.  Why won't this work?

Thanks!

Comment: because you are not saying to which user you are going to switch to.............. just type :  " su - " (yes dash after space without anything else) which by it's understanding got to root.....

Comment: Don't use su use sudo.  If you need a root shell type `sudo -s` or `sudo sh`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No need to make up a root password. Try
`sudo su`
and type your user password.

Comment: 'sudo su -' will work just fine. Don't set the root password unless you have to.

Comment: On newer `sudo` releases, `sudo -i` is the same as `sudo su -`.

Comment: sudo su is only alowed if your account has admin privileges .. comming from the windows world => I don't work that way :-)

Answer (score 20):

Others have mentioned the details of the root account. However, you don't even need `su`. Just use `sudo -i` and you get an interactive root console anyway.

Answer (score 4):

For `su` you need to enter root password. For `sudo` you have to enter your own password and you should be listed in sudoers list. Since you have not set root password or root password is different then your password, `su` is not accepting your password.

Answer (score 3):

The root password on OS X is disabled; it is *not* the same as your `sudo` password.

Say `sudo passwd root` if you want to make a root password, then `su` will work as desired. However, *make this password differ from your regular user password* in the interest of security.

Answer (score 2):

The `su` program expects you to supply the password of the user you become.

The `sudo` program expects you to provide your own password.  The configuration file for `sudo` controls what you can do with it.  With `su`, knowledge of the other persons password is sufficient.

Using `sudo` is much better; it doesn't require shared passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience:

Unless the account you are logged in as has "admin" privileges, you are not allowed to `su` or `sudo`.

What I did is create a second account "Administrator" (admin) that has admin privileges then

- `su admin`
- enter admin's password
- `sudo su` -
- enter admin's password

and then the shell I'm in is root.

Answer (score 1):

My advice: Modify the file `su` in `/etc/pam.d` by inserting the group you intend to enable for su-ing the root to `pam_group.so group=admin,<yourgroup>` where `<yourgroup>` may be `staff` (=standard users) for example.

In order to do this you have to be root already (admin is not sufficient).

Comment: Sry - The interpreter ate my brackets and the content between them ;-) Add "staff" after "group=admin," to have success.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can [enable](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) the root user (and set a password) like that.

People will recommend to use `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the suggestions above mention using `sudo su` will work. But there is a little bit of history behind this.

First of all, sudo and su are two different commands. `sudo` requires the password of the current user whereas `su` requires the password of the target user.

That's why using `sudo` is preffered as there is no exchange of information.

Based on this all Mac and Ubuntu-based releases are sudo-only, meaning the root account is not active by default. While installing a MacOS or Ubuntu OS, you create a user automatically labeled as part of the sudoers group. However, there is no root account setup. To enable the root user, you need to activate it manually.

To activate the root user run:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Next, the output asks to set the password for the root user. Type and retype a secure password, then hit Enter. The system should notify you the password has been updated successfully.

Hope this clears out any confusion there might be.